# Localisation of URLs for English Speaking Countries - iOS

Tags: ios, localization, locale

So here's the problem...

My app will have a link to buy a product from a global online retailer, however in the UK it will come from "shop.co.uk", in the US "shop.com", Australia "shop.oz.au", etc

How do I set the locale to location rather than language, as they are all English speaking countries?

Many thanks in advance

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this code you can get the country from the current locale, and with this you can choose the proper URL

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
```

Comment: by the way, the country code follow the [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

Comment: So this will have to be coded in rather than using the localization built into XCode?

Comment: no, not at all, this is independent on the "default" localization, you can add this code to change the value of the retailer domain based on the user country

Comment: ah yep, got it now. Cheers tkanzakic :)